# event.currentTarget is undefined after emulating click on element with jQuery .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, properties

I am using tabs from w3, in one of the tabs I have PHP script that reloads the page, after that I need to activate that same tab and set the class on it.

In example below that line is:

```
evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
```

I can activate that tab (IN example:`Tokyo`) by running:

```
$("#tab-bilj").click();
```

But I am getting `evt.currentTarget` error when setting the class.

How can I emulate that click so it will emulate currentTarget also?

I tired to simply add class with click and would ignore the error, but it wont work.

```
$("#tab-bilj").click().addClass("w3-red");
```

**EDIT:**

i know setting timeout on adding class would do the trick.

```
setTimeout(function() {
$("#tab-bilj").addClass("w3-red");
      }, 600);
```

But I would like to fix it thru presented function with currentTarget because i have modified that script to my needs and among other things using cockles etc as well clearing console error. Also to learn how...

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tab-bilj").click();
});
```

```css
/* W3.CSS 4.13 June 2019 by Jan Egil and Borge Refsnes */
html{box-sizing:border-box}*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:inherit}
/* Extract from normalize.css by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal git.io/normalize */
html{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,main,menu,nav,section{display:block}summary{display:list-item}
audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block}progress{vertical-align:baseline}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}
a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline-width:0}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}
b,strong{font-weight:bolder}dfn{font-style:italic}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
sub{bottom:-0.25em}sup{top:-0.5em}figure{margin:1em 40px}img{border-style:none}
code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}
button,input,select,textarea,optgroup{font:inherit;margin:0}optgroup{font-weight:bold}
button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}
button,[type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button}
button::-moz-focus-inner,[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}
button:-moz-focusring,[type=button]:-moz-focusring,[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,[type=submit]:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}
legend{color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;white-space:normal}textarea{overflow:auto}
[type=checkbox],[type=radio]{padding:0}
[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}
[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}
[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}
::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}
/* End extract */
html,body{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:1.5}html{overflow-x:hidden}
h1{font-size:36px}h2{font-size:30px}h3{font-size:24px}h4{font-size:20px}h5{font-size:18px}h6{font-size:16px}.w3-serif{font-family:serif}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400;margin:10px 0}.w3-wide{letter-spacing:4px}
hr{border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee;margin:20px 0}
.w3-image{max-width:100%;height:auto}img{vertical-align:middle}a{color:inherit}
.w3-table,.w3-table-all{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;display:table}.w3-table-all{border:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-bordered tr,.w3-table-all tr{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.w3-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#fff}.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-hoverable tbody tr:hover,.w3-ul.w3-hoverable li:hover{background-color:#ccc}.w3-centered tr th,.w3-centered tr td{text-align:center}
.w3-table td,.w3-table th,.w3-table-all td,.w3-table-all th{padding:8px 8px;display:table-cell;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.w3-table th:first-child,.w3-table td:first-child,.w3-table-all th:first-child,.w3-table-all td:first-child{padding-left:16px}
.w3-btn,.w3-button{border:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none;color:inherit;background-color:inherit;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap}
.w3-btn:hover{box-shadow:0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}
.w3-btn,.w3-button{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}   
.w3-disabled,.w3-btn:disabled,.w3-button:disabled{cursor:not-allowed;opacity:0.3}.w3-disabled *,:disabled *{pointer-events:none}
.w3-btn.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn:disabled:hover{box-shadow:none}
.w3-badge,.w3-tag{background-color:#000;color:#fff;display:inline-block;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;text-align:center}.w3-badge{border-radius:50%}
.w3-ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0}.w3-ul li{padding:8px 16px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.w3-ul li:last-child{border-bottom:none}
.w3-tooltip,.w3-display-container{position:relative}.w3-tooltip .w3-text{display:none}.w3-tooltip:hover .w3-text{display:inline-block}
.w3-ripple:active{opacity:0.5}.w3-ripple{transition:opacity 0s}
.w3-input{padding:8px;display:block;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;width:100%}
.w3-select{padding:9px 0;width:100%;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-dropdown-click,.w3-dropdown-hover{position:relative;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer}
.w3-dropdown-hover:hover .w3-dropdown-content{display:block}
.w3-dropdown-hover:first-child,.w3-dropdown-click:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
.w3-dropdown-hover:hover > .w3-button:first-child,.w3-dropdown-click:hover > .w3-button:first-child{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
.w3-dropdown-content{cursor:auto;color:#000;background-color:#fff;display:none;position:absolute;min-width:160px;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:1}
.w3-check,.w3-radio{width:24px;height:24px;position:relative;top:6px}
.w3-sidebar{height:100%;width:200px;background-color:#fff;position:fixed!important;z-index:1;overflow:auto}
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-hover,.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click{width:100%}
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-hover .w3-dropdown-content,.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click .w3-dropdown-content{min-width:100%}
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-hover .w3-button,.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click .w3-button{width:100%;text-align:left;padding:8px 16px}
.w3-main,#main{transition:margin-left .4s}
.w3-modal{z-index:3;display:none;padding-top:100px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)}
.w3-modal-content{margin:auto;background-color:#fff;position:relative;padding:0;outline:0;width:600px}
.w3-bar{width:100%;overflow:hidden}.w3-center .w3-bar{display:inline-block;width:auto}
.w3-bar .w3-bar-item{padding:8px 16px;float:left;width:auto;border:none;display:block;outline:0}
.w3-bar .w3-dropdown-hover,.w3-bar .w3-dropdown-click{position:static;float:left}
.w3-bar .w3-button{white-space:normal}
.w3-bar-block .w3-bar-item{width:100%;display:block;padding:8px 16px;text-align:left;border:none;white-space:normal;float:none;outline:0}
.w3-bar-block.w3-center .w3-bar-item{text-align:center}.w3-block{display:block;width:100%}
.w3-responsive{display:block;overflow-x:auto}
.w3-container:after,.w3-container:before,.w3-panel:after,.w3-panel:before,.w3-row:after,.w3-row:before,.w3-row-padding:after,.w3-row-padding:before,
.w3-cell-row:before,.w3-cell-row:after,.w3-clear:after,.w3-clear:before,.w3-bar:before,.w3-bar:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}
.w3-col,.w3-half,.w3-third,.w3-twothird,.w3-threequarter,.w3-quarter{float:left;width:100%}
.w3-col.s1{width:8.33333%}.w3-col.s2{width:16.66666%}.w3-col.s3{width:24.99999%}.w3-col.s4{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.s5{width:41.66666%}.w3-col.s6{width:49.99999%}.w3-col.s7{width:58.33333%}.w3-col.s8{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.s9{width:74.99999%}.w3-col.s10{width:83.33333%}.w3-col.s11{width:91.66666%}.w3-col.s12{width:99.99999%}
@media (min-width:601px){.w3-col.m1{width:8.33333%}.w3-col.m2{width:16.66666%}.w3-col.m3,.w3-quarter{width:24.99999%}.w3-col.m4,.w3-third{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.m5{width:41.66666%}.w3-col.m6,.w3-half{width:49.99999%}.w3-col.m7{width:58.33333%}.w3-col.m8,.w3-twothird{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.m9,.w3-threequarter{width:74.99999%}.w3-col.m10{width:83.33333%}.w3-col.m11{width:91.66666%}.w3-col.m12{width:99.99999%}}
@media (min-width:993px){.w3-col.l1{width:8.33333%}.w3-col.l2{width:16.66666%}.w3-col.l3{width:24.99999%}.w3-col.l4{width:33.33333%}
.w3-col.l5{width:41.66666%}.w3-col.l6{width:49.99999%}.w3-col.l7{width:58.33333%}.w3-col.l8{width:66.66666%}
.w3-col.l9{width:74.99999%}.w3-col.l10{width:83.33333%}.w3-col.l11{width:91.66666%}.w3-col.l12{width:99.99999%}}
.w3-rest{overflow:hidden}.w3-stretch{margin-left:-16px;margin-right:-16px}
.w3-content,.w3-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.w3-content{max-width:980px}.w3-auto{max-width:1140px}
.w3-cell-row{display:table;width:100%}.w3-cell{display:table-cell}
.w3-cell-top{vertical-align:top}.w3-cell-middle{vertical-align:middle}.w3-cell-bottom{vertical-align:bottom}
.w3-hide{display:none!important}.w3-show-block,.w3-show{display:block!important}.w3-show-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}
@media (max-width:1205px){.w3-auto{max-width:95%}}
@media (max-width:600px){.w3-modal-content{margin:0 10px;width:auto!important}.w3-modal{padding-top:30px}
.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content{position:relative}  
.w3-hide-small{display:none!important}.w3-mobile{display:block;width:100%!important}.w3-bar-item.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile{text-align:center}
.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-btn,.w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-button,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-btn,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-button{width:100%}}
@media (max-width:768px){.w3-modal-content{width:500px}.w3-modal{padding-top:50px}}
@media (min-width:993px){.w3-modal-content{width:900px}.w3-hide-large{display:none!important}.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:block!important}}
@media (max-width:992px) and (min-width:601px){.w3-hide-medium{display:none!important}}
@media (max-width:992px){.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:none}.w3-main{margin-left:0!important;margin-right:0!important}.w3-auto{max-width:100%}}
.w3-top,.w3-bottom{position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:1}.w3-top{top:0}.w3-bottom{bottom:0}
.w3-overlay{position:fixed;display:none;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z-index:2}
.w3-display-topleft{position:absolute;left:0;top:0}.w3-display-topright{position:absolute;right:0;top:0}
.w3-display-bottomleft{position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0}.w3-display-bottomright{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0}
.w3-display-middle{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
.w3-display-left{position:absolute;top:50%;left:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-0%,-50%)}
.w3-display-right{position:absolute;top:50%;right:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(0%,-50%)}
.w3-display-topmiddle{position:absolute;left:50%;top:0;transform:translate(-50%,0%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%)}
.w3-display-bottommiddle{position:absolute;left:50%;bottom:0;transform:translate(-50%,0%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%)}
.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-hover{display:block}.w3-display-container:hover span.w3-display-hover{display:inline-block}.w3-display-hover{display:none}
.w3-display-position{position:absolute}
.w3-circle{border-radius:50%}
.w3-round-small{border-radius:2px}.w3-round,.w3-round-medium{border-radius:4px}.w3-round-large{border-radius:8px}.w3-round-xlarge{border-radius:16px}.w3-round-xxlarge{border-radius:32px}
.w3-row-padding,.w3-row-padding>.w3-half,.w3-row-padding>.w3-third,.w3-row-padding>.w3-twothird,.w3-row-padding>.w3-threequarter,.w3-row-padding>.w3-quarter,.w3-row-padding>.w3-col{padding:0 8px}
.w3-container,.w3-panel{padding:0.01em 16px}.w3-panel{margin-top:16px;margin-bottom:16px}
.w3-code,.w3-codespan{font-family:Consolas,"courier new";font-size:16px}
.w3-code{width:auto;background-color:#fff;padding:8px 12px;border-left:4px solid #4CAF50;word-wrap:break-word}
.w3-codespan{color:crimson;background-color:#f1f1f1;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;font-size:110%}
.w3-card,.w3-card-2{box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)}
.w3-card-4,.w3-hover-shadow:hover{box-shadow:0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}
.w3-spin{animation:w3-spin 2s infinite linear}@keyframes w3-spin{0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{transform:rotate(359deg)}}
.w3-animate-fading{animation:fading 10s infinite}@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}
.w3-animate-opacity{animation:opac 0.8s}@keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-top{position:relative;animation:animatetop 0.4s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-left{position:relative;animation:animateleft 0.4s}@keyframes animateleft{from{left:-300px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-right{position:relative;animation:animateright 0.4s}@keyframes animateright{from{right:-300px;opacity:0} to{right:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-bottom{position:relative;animation:animatebottom 0.4s}@keyframes animatebottom{from{bottom:-300px;opacity:0} to{bottom:0;opacity:1}}
.w3-animate-zoom {animation:animatezoom 0.6s}@keyframes animatezoom{from{transform:scale(0)} to{transform:scale(1)}}
.w3-animate-input{transition:width 0.4s ease-in-out}.w3-animate-input:focus{width:100%!important}
.w3-opacity,.w3-hover-opacity:hover{opacity:0.60}.w3-opacity-off,.w3-hover-opacity-off:hover{opacity:1}
.w3-opacity-max{opacity:0.25}.w3-opacity-min{opacity:0.75}
.w3-greyscale-max,.w3-grayscale-max,.w3-hover-greyscale:hover,.w3-hover-grayscale:hover{filter:grayscale(100%)}
.w3-greyscale,.w3-grayscale{filter:grayscale(75%)}.w3-greyscale-min,.w3-grayscale-min{filter:grayscale(50%)}
.w3-sepia{filter:sepia(75%)}.w3-sepia-max,.w3-hover-sepia:hover{filter:sepia(100%)}.w3-sepia-min{filter:sepia(50%)}
.w3-tiny{font-size:10px!important}.w3-small{font-size:12px!important}.w3-medium{font-size:15px!important}.w3-large{font-size:18px!important}
.w3-xlarge{font-size:24px!important}.w3-xxlarge{font-size:36px!important}.w3-xxxlarge{font-size:48px!important}.w3-jumbo{font-size:64px!important}
.w3-left-align{text-align:left!important}.w3-right-align{text-align:right!important}.w3-justify{text-align:justify!important}.w3-center{text-align:center!important}
.w3-border-0{border:0!important}.w3-border{border:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-top{border-top:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-bottom{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-left{border-left:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-right{border-right:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-topbar{border-top:6px solid #ccc!important}.w3-bottombar{border-bottom:6px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-leftbar{border-left:6px solid #ccc!important}.w3-rightbar{border-right:6px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-section,.w3-code{margin-top:16px!important;margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-margin{margin:16px!important}.w3-margin-top{margin-top:16px!important}.w3-margin-bottom{margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-margin-left{margin-left:16px!important}.w3-margin-right{margin-right:16px!important}
.w3-padding-small{padding:4px 8px!important}.w3-padding{padding:8px 16px!important}.w3-padding-large{padding:12px 24px!important}
.w3-padding-16{padding-top:16px!important;padding-bottom:16px!important}.w3-padding-24{padding-top:24px!important;padding-bottom:24px!important}
.w3-padding-32{padding-top:32px!important;padding-bottom:32px!important}.w3-padding-48{padding-top:48px!important;padding-bottom:48px!important}
.w3-padding-64{padding-top:64px!important;padding-bottom:64px!important}
.w3-left{float:left!important}.w3-right{float:right!important}
.w3-button:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ccc!important}
.w3-transparent,.w3-hover-none:hover{background-color:transparent!important}
.w3-hover-none:hover{box-shadow:none!important}
/* Colors */
.w3-amber,.w3-hover-amber:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffc107!important}
.w3-aqua,.w3-hover-aqua:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#00ffff!important}
.w3-blue,.w3-hover-blue:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#2196F3!important}
.w3-light-blue,.w3-hover-light-blue:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#87CEEB!important}
.w3-brown,.w3-hover-brown:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#795548!important}
.w3-cyan,.w3-hover-cyan:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#00bcd4!important}
.w3-blue-grey,.w3-hover-blue-grey:hover,.w3-blue-gray,.w3-hover-blue-gray:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#607d8b!important}
.w3-green,.w3-hover-green:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#4CAF50!important}
.w3-light-green,.w3-hover-light-green:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#8bc34a!important}
.w3-indigo,.w3-hover-indigo:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#3f51b5!important}
.w3-khaki,.w3-hover-khaki:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#f0e68c!important}
.w3-lime,.w3-hover-lime:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#cddc39!important}
.w3-orange,.w3-hover-orange:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ff9800!important}
.w3-deep-orange,.w3-hover-deep-orange:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#ff5722!important}
.w3-pink,.w3-hover-pink:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#e91e63!important}
.w3-purple,.w3-hover-purple:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#9c27b0!important}
.w3-deep-purple,.w3-hover-deep-purple:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#673ab7!important}
.w3-red,.w3-hover-red:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#f44336!important}
.w3-sand,.w3-hover-sand:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#fdf5e6!important}
.w3-teal,.w3-hover-teal:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#009688!important}
.w3-yellow,.w3-hover-yellow:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffeb3b!important}
.w3-white,.w3-hover-white:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#fff!important}
.w3-black,.w3-hover-black:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#000!important}
.w3-grey,.w3-hover-grey:hover,.w3-gray,.w3-hover-gray:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#9e9e9e!important}
.w3-light-grey,.w3-hover-light-grey:hover,.w3-light-gray,.w3-hover-light-gray:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#f1f1f1!important}
.w3-dark-grey,.w3-hover-dark-grey:hover,.w3-dark-gray,.w3-hover-dark-gray:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#616161!important}
.w3-pale-red,.w3-hover-pale-red:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffdddd!important}
.w3-pale-green,.w3-hover-pale-green:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ddffdd!important}
.w3-pale-yellow,.w3-hover-pale-yellow:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ffffcc!important}
.w3-pale-blue,.w3-hover-pale-blue:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ddffff!important}
.w3-text-amber,.w3-hover-text-amber:hover{color:#ffc107!important}
.w3-text-aqua,.w3-hover-text-aqua:hover{color:#00ffff!important}
.w3-text-blue,.w3-hover-text-blue:hover{color:#2196F3!important}
.w3-text-light-blue,.w3-hover-text-light-blue:hover{color:#87CEEB!important}
.w3-text-brown,.w3-hover-text-brown:hover{color:#795548!important}
.w3-text-cyan,.w3-hover-text-cyan:hover{color:#00bcd4!important}
.w3-text-blue-grey,.w3-hover-text-blue-grey:hover,.w3-text-blue-gray,.w3-hover-text-blue-gray:hover{color:#607d8b!important}
.w3-text-green,.w3-hover-text-green:hover{color:#4CAF50!important}
.w3-text-light-green,.w3-hover-text-light-green:hover{color:#8bc34a!important}
.w3-text-indigo,.w3-hover-text-indigo:hover{color:#3f51b5!important}
.w3-text-khaki,.w3-hover-text-khaki:hover{color:#b4aa50!important}
.w3-text-lime,.w3-hover-text-lime:hover{color:#cddc39!important}
.w3-text-orange,.w3-hover-text-orange:hover{color:#ff9800!important}
.w3-text-deep-orange,.w3-hover-text-deep-orange:hover{color:#ff5722!important}
.w3-text-pink,.w3-hover-text-pink:hover{color:#e91e63!important}
.w3-text-purple,.w3-hover-text-purple:hover{color:#9c27b0!important}
.w3-text-deep-purple,.w3-hover-text-deep-purple:hover{color:#673ab7!important}
.w3-text-red,.w3-hover-text-red:hover{color:#f44336!important}
.w3-text-sand,.w3-hover-text-sand:hover{color:#fdf5e6!important}
.w3-text-teal,.w3-hover-text-teal:hover{color:#009688!important}
.w3-text-yellow,.w3-hover-text-yellow:hover{color:#d2be0e!important}
.w3-text-white,.w3-hover-text-white:hover{color:#fff!important}
.w3-text-black,.w3-hover-text-black:hover{color:#000!important}
.w3-text-grey,.w3-hover-text-grey:hover,.w3-text-gray,.w3-hover-text-gray:hover{color:#757575!important}
.w3-text-light-grey,.w3-hover-text-light-grey:hover,.w3-text-light-gray,.w3-hover-text-light-gray:hover{color:#f1f1f1!important}
.w3-text-dark-grey,.w3-hover-text-dark-grey:hover,.w3-text-dark-gray,.w3-hover-text-dark-gray:hover{color:#3a3a3a!important}
.w3-border-amber,.w3-hover-border-amber:hover{border-color:#ffc107!important}
.w3-border-aqua,.w3-hover-border-aqua:hover{border-color:#00ffff!important}
.w3-border-blue,.w3-hover-border-blue:hover{border-color:#2196F3!important}
.w3-border-light-blue,.w3-hover-border-light-blue:hover{border-color:#87CEEB!important}
.w3-border-brown,.w3-hover-border-brown:hover{border-color:#795548!important}
.w3-border-cyan,.w3-hover-border-cyan:hover{border-color:#00bcd4!important}
.w3-border-blue-grey,.w3-hover-border-blue-grey:hover,.w3-border-blue-gray,.w3-hover-border-blue-gray:hover{border-color:#607d8b!important}
.w3-border-green,.w3-hover-border-green:hover{border-color:#4CAF50!important}
.w3-border-light-green,.w3-hover-border-light-green:hover{border-color:#8bc34a!important}
.w3-border-indigo,.w3-hover-border-indigo:hover{border-color:#3f51b5!important}
.w3-border-khaki,.w3-hover-border-khaki:hover{border-color:#f0e68c!important}
.w3-border-lime,.w3-hover-border-lime:hover{border-color:#cddc39!important}
.w3-border-orange,.w3-hover-border-orange:hover{border-color:#ff9800!important}
.w3-border-deep-orange,.w3-hover-border-deep-orange:hover{border-color:#ff5722!important}
.w3-border-pink,.w3-hover-border-pink:hover{border-color:#e91e63!important}
.w3-border-purple,.w3-hover-border-purple:hover{border-color:#9c27b0!important}
.w3-border-deep-purple,.w3-hover-border-deep-purple:hover{border-color:#673ab7!important}
.w3-border-red,.w3-hover-border-red:hover{border-color:#f44336!important}
.w3-border-sand,.w3-hover-border-sand:hover{border-color:#fdf5e6!important}
.w3-border-teal,.w3-hover-border-teal:hover{border-color:#009688!important}
.w3-border-yellow,.w3-hover-border-yellow:hover{border-color:#ffeb3b!important}
.w3-border-white,.w3-hover-border-white:hover{border-color:#fff!important}
.w3-border-black,.w3-hover-border-black:hover{border-color:#000!important}
.w3-border-grey,.w3-hover-border-grey:hover,.w3-border-gray,.w3-hover-border-gray:hover{border-color:#9e9e9e!important}
.w3-border-light-grey,.w3-hover-border-light-grey:hover,.w3-border-light-gray,.w3-hover-border-light-gray:hover{border-color:#f1f1f1!important}
.w3-border-dark-grey,.w3-hover-border-dark-grey:hover,.w3-border-dark-gray,.w3-hover-border-dark-gray:hover{border-color:#616161!important}
.w3-border-pale-red,.w3-hover-border-pale-red:hover{border-color:#ffe7e7!important}.w3-border-pale-green,.w3-hover-border-pale-green:hover{border-color:#e7ffe7!important}
.w3-border-pale-yellow,.w3-hover-border-pale-yellow:hover{border-color:#ffffcc!important}.w3-border-pale-blue,.w3-hover-border-pale-blue:hover{border-color:#e7ffff!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

  <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink w3-red" onclick="openCity(event,'London')">London</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button id="tab-bilj" class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="London" class="w3-container w3-border city">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to what you're trying to do.  There's no need to use jQuery in this. If the click event is the only reason you're loading a MASSIVE library, then don't.  Below will work on **Most** browsers.

Change your buttons as follows:

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink w3-red" onclick="openCity(this,'London')">London</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(this,'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button id="tab-bilj" class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(this,'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>
```

Your code can be simplified MUCH more if you use pure JavaScript.
Code:

```
function openCity(target, cityName) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".city").forEach(y => y.style.display = "none");//hides all cities
        document.querySelectorAll('.tablink').forEach(y => y.className.replace("ws-red", ""));
        document.querySelectorAll(".w3-red").forEach(z => z.classList.remove("w3-red"))
        document.querySelector(`#${cityName}`).style.display = "block"
        target.classList.add("w3-red");
    }
```

Instead of that jQuery, use:

```
document.onreadystatechange= document.querySelector("#tab-bilj").click();
```

Now, if you're stuck on using jQuery, then you can do the following:

```
function openCity(target, cityName) {
    $('.city').css('display', 'none');//will change all
    $('.w3-red').removeClass('w3-red');//removes all instances of this class
    $('#' + cityName).css('display', '');
    $(target).addClass('w3-red');
}

$(document).ready(function () { $("#tab-bilj").click(); });
```

The above is for if you use the buttons I provided.  If you want to use the event as with your original buttons, do this:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    $('.city').css('display', 'none');//will change all
    $('.w3-red').removeClass('w3-red');//removes all instances of this class
    $('#' + cityName).css('display', '');
    $(evt.target).addClass('w3-red');
}
```

The pure JavaScript above will be MUCH faster for you, and it won't rely on an enormous library.  Up to you.

**Edit:** Added a more advanced method
If you would rather not show the event name on the buttons, you can add an event listener instead using the following code.  No need to pass events or references.

Buttons:

```
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink">London</button>
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink">Paris</button>
<button id="tab-bilj" class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink">Tokyo</button>
```

New Code:

```
function openCity(cityName) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".city").forEach(y => y.style.display ="none");//hides all cities
    document.querySelectorAll('.tablink').forEach(y => y.className.replace("ws-red", ""));
    document.querySelectorAll(".w3-red").forEach(z => z.classList.remove("w3-red"))
    document.querySelector(`#${cityName}`).style.display = "block"  
}
    document.querySelectorAll('.w3-button')
      .forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click', function() {
          openCity(x.innerText);
          x.classList.add("w3-red");        
    }));

document.querySelector("#tab-bilj").click();
```

Comment: I appreciate the "simple"  versions, but i knew how to do this myself, this is example. I already have heavily modified version. That being said,  both `document.querySelector("#tab-bilj").click();`  and `document.onreadystatechange= document.querySelector("#tab-bilj").click();` fixed the issue, for some reason my and yours `$(document).ready(. ` is not working in my production and this snippet example.

Comment: I don't know your specific firewall config, but for my work environment, cloudflare is blocked.  I would recommend pulling the jquery from Google's CDN :
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Also, use event.target instead of event.currentTarget

Comment: Well now with just  event.target now even  jQuery works... It was that simple... Thanks for the help.